# iPad keyboard, UITextField, strange behaviour

Tags: objective-c, ipad, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a `UITextField` that moves the view up/down when the keyboard moves in/out.

```
- (IBAction)moveUp;
- (IBAction)moveDown;
```

I move the view up by "Editing Did Begin" and down by "Did End On Exit" (which I found in some thread here in StackOverflow).

However, the view does not move down, when the button (bottom right) "hide keyboard" is hit.
This obviously does respond to "Editing Did End".

The strange thing is, if I also connect "Editing Did End" to moveDown, the method moveDown will be invoked 2x (and moves to far down screen!)
If I then diconnect-connect "Did End On Exit", the view does not disappear by hitting the 'return' button, as it did before.

Any idea what goes wrong here?

//Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Instead of connecting your methods to control events on the the text field, you should fire your method in response to two notifications, `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`. Simply add yourself as an observer for these notifications in `-viewDidLoad` and remove yourself in `-viewDidUnload`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(moveUp) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(moveDown) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the  "Editing Did Begin" and "Editing Did End on Exit" which are defined by UIControl, I'd suggest you use assign a delegate for your text field and use the textFieldDidEndEditing: method defined by the UITextFieldDelegate protocol.  I believe this will fire when you want.

Comment: Still the same strange behaviour. I just solved it by a workaround. I will call textFieldShouldReturn: with nothing else but resign the first responder. All the other necessary task will be handled in textFieldDidEndEditing: since this will be called anyway. However, textFieldShouldReturn: must be available! Will not try to understand it. Now it works. §$"!!@&!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are connecting to "Did End On Exit", and not to "Editing Sid End". These names are a little bit confusing.